# How do I prevent clicking multiple decimal point from the user in a javaScript calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a javaScript calculator with html, css and javascript. Here i've created onclick events with function , and for all the button in the calculator i've created a single function now I'm not able to prevent clicking multiple decimal point from the user.

I've tried with loops and the Includes method tried to do it by getting the index of the firs decimal point inputed by the user but didn't work. I want that in a input field there will be one decimal point and if the user try to input multiple decimal point, it won't work.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Please edit your question to show what research you've done and any attempts you've made to solve the problem yourself

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: You can check if a decimal point already exists in the input field before appending another one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.